# List sorts correctly one time, then the subsequent times it sorts incorrectly

Tags: python, sorting

I have sorted through a csv file, and converted it to a list of lists. I now need to sort that list of lists based on a specific index.

The following block of code works:

```
def highestPoint(copiedList):

    copiedList.sort(key=lambda x: x[2], reverse=True)

    date = copiedList[0][0]
    value = float(copiedList[0][2])

    print("\nThe day where the stock reached its highest point is",
          date, "with" " a value of {:,.2f}".format(value))
```

Now, I assumed that I could copy and paste this block of code, replacing the `[2]` in both spots in order to sort the list and print the results.

Clearly, the words in the print statement are changed, as is the name of the procedure, but everything else is the same.

We have sample output, and my answers are not coming out the same. The first code works, but the other ones do not.

Each block of code is its own procedure, passing the `copiedList` each time. The `copiedList` is just a shallow copy of the original `dataList`.

Comment: Using `max()` and `min()` instead of `sort()` would speed-up you code a lot. They have the same `key` argument.

Comment: I changed `copiedList.sort(key = lambda x: x[2])` to `copiedList = max(key = lambda x: x[2]` and it produced the integer 2 where the date was and 1.00 where the value should be. Did I do something wrong?

Comment: Yes. You don't need to modify `copiedList` at all if you only want the maximum value. You'd just do: `maxentry = max(copiedList, key=lambda x: x[2])`, `date = maxentry[0]`, `value = float(maxentry[2])`. Note: If you're converting to `float`, the key function might be better as `lambda x: float(x[2])` to match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think when you read in the file you did not convert the str to float,therefore the sort function may not work.

for example:

```
print('10' > '5')
False
```

I suggest you convert number to float than sort

when you sort string numerically, it will be like following:

```
numString = ["1","5000","3","6","30","4","2","200"]
print(sorted(numString))

['1', '2', '200', '3', '30', '4', '5000', '6']
```

Comment: Converting to a float worked. Was my previous code trying to sort the floats as strings?

Comment: @Brett the previous code is comparing strings. see my new update